# Call the custom Log Function inside Invoke Command

Tags: powershell

I have written a custom Write-Log Function. If I use the Write-Log function inside the Invoke, I am getting below error message "Error on remote execution: The term 'Write-Log' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

I'm using Powershell 5.1. I did try to use ${function:Write-Log} but it didn't work.

```
Function Write-Log([string]$ComputerList,$message, $level="INFO") {
    $date_stamp = Get-Date -Format s
    $log_entry = "$date_stamp - $level - $message"
    $log_file = "$tmp_dir\upgrade_powershell.log"
    Write-Verbose -Message $log_entry
    Add-Content -Path $log_file -Value $log_entry
}

Function Start-Process ($ComputerList) {    
    Return Invoke-Command -computername $Computer -ScriptBlock {
                Param($file)
                $Application = $args[0]
                $ApplicationName = $Application.Substring($Application.LastIndexOf('\')+1)
                $ApplicationFolderPath = $Application.Substring(0,$Application.LastIndexOf('\'))
                $ApplicationExt = $Application.Substring($Application.LastIndexOf('.')+1)
    Write-Log -message "Installing $file on $($env:COMPUTERNAME)"
    $p = Start-Process $file -Wait -Passthru

    $p.WaitForExit()
                $p.WaitForExit()
                if ($p.ExitCode -ne 0) {
                    Write-Log -message "Failed installing with error code $($p.ExitCode)"  -level "ERROR"
                    $Return = $($env:COMPUTERNAME)
                }
                else{
                    $Return = 0

        if ($p.ExitCode -ne 0 -and $p.ExitCode -ne 3010) {
        $log_msg = "$($error_msg): exit code $p.ExitCode"
        Write-Log  -message $log_msg -level "ERROR"
        #throw $log_msg
        return
      }
    if ($p.ExitCode-eq 3010) {
        Reboot-AndResume
        break
    }}


}
}
```

Comment: Start-Process is a reserved word that you shouldn't use for the name of your function. That's not the problem, though. Your code is formatted with inconsistent alignment, and it's hard to read your intent from it. I wasn't able to reproduce your issue. Maybe there was a copy-paste error.

Comment: besides the horrible misuse of `Start-Process` [*grin*], your answer is here ... How do I include a locally defined function when using PowerShell's Invoke-Command for remoting? - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367367/how-do-i-include-a-locally-defined-function-when-using-powershells-invoke-comma

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I include a locally defined function when using PowerShell's Invoke-Command for remoting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367367/how-do-i-include-a-locally-defined-function-when-using-powershells-invoke-comma)

Answer (score 0):

try including your custom function definition inside the scriptblock, sort of like this

```
invoke-command -scriptblock {
    param (
        your params
    )

    begin {
        function write-log (etc) {
            the function code
        }
    }

    process {
        your main scriptblock stuff
    }

    end {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I did try to use `${function:Write-Log}` but it didn't work.

**`${function:Write-Log}` uses [namespace variable notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375) to get the `Write-Log` function's *body* as a *script block***.

Since you're using *remoting* (you're passing a `-ComputerName` argument to `Invoke-Command`), you'll either have to pass that script block as an *argument* to the remotely executing script block, or - more conveniently - **utilize the [`$using:` scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables#using-local-variables) (PSv3+) to make a *local* variable value available *remotely***.

Unfortunately, `$using:` cannot be combined with namespace variable notation, as of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core 6.2.0 - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9204).

Therefore, with the bug present, referencing your script block as `${using:function:Write-Log}` does *not* work directly, but you can use an *intermediate variable*, and then use that to adapt [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23948626/45375), using a simplified scenario:

Note: To run this code, which simulates remoting by connecting to the same machine, make sure that [remoting is enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting) on your machine, and invoke the code *as admin*.

```
function Write-Log { 
  param([string] $ComputerList, $message, $level="INFO")      
  # For testing simply echo the arguments
  "$ComputerList, $message, $level"
}

# Recreate the function's full source code as a string.
$funcDef = "function Write-Log { ${function:Write-Log} }"

Invoke-Command -Computer . -ScriptBlock {

  # Define the Write-Log function using Invoke-Expression
  # Note: This is a rare case where use of Invoke-Expression is
  #       justified; generally, it is to be AVOIDED - see
  #       https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/
  Invoke-Expression $using:funcDef

  # Now you can call it as you would locally.
  Write-Log 'ws1 ws2' testing DEBUG

}
```

The above should return `ws1 ws2, testing, DEBUG`.

---

Of course, if the `Write-Log` source code is:

- readily available to you, and
- you don't mind *duplicating* it inside the script block,

you can just **make the function definition part of the remotely executing script block**:

```
Invoke-Command -Computer . -ScriptBlock {

  # Embedded copy of Write-Log.
  function Write-Log { 
    param([string] $ComputerList, $message, $level="INFO")      
    # For testing simply echo the arguments
    "$ComputerList, $message, $level"
  }

  # Now you can call it as you would locally.
  Write-Log 'ws1 ws2' testing DEBUG

}
```