# Invoke-Command with dynamic function name

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I found this awesome post: [Using Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock on a function with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448808/using-invoke-command-scriptblock-on-a-function-with-arguments)

I'm trying to make the function call (`${function:Foo}`) dynamic, as in I want to pass the function name.

I tried this:

```
$name = "Foo"
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ${function:$name}
```

but that fails. I also tried various escape sequences, but just can't get the function name to be dynamic.

---

EDIT: For clarity I am adding a small test script. Of course the desired result is to call the `ExternalFunction`.

```
Function ExternalFunction()
{
  write-host "I was called externally"
}

Function InternalFunction()
{
    Param ([parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$FunctionName)
    #working: Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ${function:ExternalFunction}
    #not working: Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ${invoke-expression $FunctionName}
    if (Test-Path Function:\$FunctionName) {
    #working,but how to use it in ScriptBlock?
    }
}

InternalFunction -FunctionName "ExternalFunction"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alternate solution:

```
function foo {'I am foo!'}

$name = 'foo'

$sb = (get-command $name -CommandType Function).ScriptBlock
invoke-command -scriptblock $sb
```

I am foo!

Comment: I didn't mean that you should add a working example. I was happy that the example you provided worked! :-) Thanks

Comment: Just for future reference, this will actually fail if you use it with an advanced function that has a Begin, Process or End block.  You'll get an exception about containing more than one clause.  You can get around it by using the call operator instead of Invoke-Command though.  So something like this:  & $sb "Some Function Argument"

Answer (score 2):

as simple as :

```
invoke-expression  $name
```

or if you want to keep invoke-commande for remoting for example

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { invoke-expression  $name}
```

Comment: `invoke-expression` works outside a function. But when using it together with invoke command within a function I get a `"Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ScriptBlock'. The argument is null. Supply a non-null argument and try the"`

Comment: you have an unwanted $ before your scriptblock

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following. It tests if the name specified is a valid function before it attempts to run it:

```
$myfuncnamevar = "Foo"
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
    param($name)
    if (Test-Path Function:\$name) { 
        #Function exists = run it
        & $name
    }
} -ArgumentList $myfuncnamevar
```

Comment: Test-Path does work, but how would I call it within the Invoke-Command?

Comment: I put a line at the bottom to explain it. Updated with solution now. Remember that the function needs to exist on the remote computer. If this is a local funciton, you need to pass it in the scriptblock.