# Pass a function (with arguments) as a parameter in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, functional-programming, powershell-2.0, first-class-functions

I've been successfully passing no-argument functions around in PowerShell using ScriptBlocks. However, I can't get this to work if the function has arguments. Is there a way to do this in PowerShell? (v2 preferably)

```
Function Add([int] $x, [int] $y)  
{ 
  return $x + $y 
}
Function Apply([scriptblock] $s)    
{ 
    write-host ($s.Invoke(1,2)) 
}
```

Then

```
Apply { Add }
```

writes 0 to the console. Apply does invoke `Add`, but doesn't pass any arguments in (i.e. uses the default [int] values of 0 and 0)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8448808/738851):

I wanted `${function:Add}` rather than `{ Add }` in the call to `Apply`.

Comment: Trap for young players: You can't have any spaces between the braces and the function details.  So `${ function:Add }` (leading and trailing spaces),  `${ function:Add}` (leading space) or `${function:Add }` (trailing space) will all fail with error `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.`  `${function:Add}`, without either leading or trailing space, works fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much cleaner way to do this using the PowerShell function provider.  I needed to be able to run functions from other source files with variable numbers of arguments based on an XML file provided at run time.

In developing this I wrote a small "Hello World" tester in two source files which should be fairly self-explanatory (the magic line is "**$x = (& $func $parm)**"):

1. "Hello.ps1" - The remote function

```js
    function Hello ($in) {
     
        write-Host "Hello $in"
    }
```

2. "Hello2.ps1" - The executing routine

```js
    function exec-script ($file, $func, $parm) {
       
       Invoke-Expression $file    
       
       $x = (& $func $parm)
       
       $x
        
       }
    
    exec-script -file ".\Hello" -func "Hello" -parm "World"
```