# Powershell: Don't wait on function return

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing

I have a Powershell script where I am invoking a function called generate_html.

Is there a way to call the function and not wait on its return before proceeding to the next function call?

I would prefer not to have to resort to breaking it out into multiple scripts and running those scripts at same time.

```
function generate_html($var)
{
...
}

generate_html team1
generate_html team2
```

Comment: Look at using jobs: `get-help about_jobs`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can start a method as an asynchronous job, using the `Start-Job` cmdlet.

So, you would do something like this:

```
function generate_html($var)
{
#snipped
}

Start-Job -ScriptBlock { generate_html team1 }
```

If you need to monitor if the job is finished, either store the output of Start-Job or use `Get-Job` to get all jobs started in the current session, pulling out the one you want.
Once you have that, check the `State` property to see if the value is `Finished`

**EDIT**:
Actually, my mistake, the job will be in another thread, so functions defined or not available (not in a module that powershell knows about) in the thread from which you start your job are not available.

Try declaring your function as a scriptblock:

```
$generateHtml = { 
    param($var)
    #snipped
}

Start-Job -ScriptBlock $generateHtml -ArgumentList team1
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $generateHtml -ArgumentList team2
```

Comment: Note the `-Keep` flag on the receive-job can prevent the automatic deletion of results after receiving.  `receive-job -name MyJob -Keep`  In case that becomes an issue for any readers.

Comment: I get the following error:  The term 'generate_html' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was my function would create a Windows Forms GUI, and stopped the remaining script from running until I closed out the Windows Forms GUI.  I found the solution, but for a different command, here: [Using Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock on a function with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448808/using-invoke-command-scriptblock-on-a-function-with-arguments).

Within the `-ScriptBlock` parameter, use `${function:YOUR_FUNCTION}`

```
function generate_html($var) {
    # code
}

Start-Job -ScriptBlock ${function:generate_html} -ArgumentList "team1"
Start-Job -ScriptBlock ${function:generate_html} -ArgumentList "team2"
```

Also, if you don't want console output from `Start-Job`, just pipe it to `Out-Null`:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock ${function:generate_html} -ArgumentList "team1" | Out-Null
Start-Job -ScriptBlock ${function:generate_html} -ArgumentList "team2" | Out-Null
```