# Invoke-Command won't accept -Path as a variable

Tags: powershell

I am trying to execute a simple `Test-Path` query to a remote computer using `Invoke-Command`, but I am struggling with a strange error.

This works:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName COMPUTER001 -ScriptBlock {Test-Path -Path "c:\windows\system.ini"}
```

This fails with "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.":

```
$p_FileName = "c:\windows\system.ini"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName COMPUTER001 -ScriptBlock {Test-Path -Path $p_FileName}
```

I have tried using both `$p_FileName` and `$($p_FileName)`, but no luck.

Any suggestions, and hopefully an explanation as to what is happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock on a function with arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448808/using-invoke-command-scriptblock-on-a-function-with-arguments)

Answer (score 4):

You have to pass local variables used in the script block through the -ArgumentList parameter:

```
$p_FileName = "c:\windows\system.ini"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName COMPUTER001 -ScriptBlock {Test-Path -Path $args[0]} -ArgumentList $p_FileName
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a scope issue. The scope within the script block that runs on the remote server cannot access your local variables. There are several ways around this. My favorite is the $Using: scope but a lot of people do not know about it.

```
$p_FileName = "c:\windows\system.ini"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName COMPUTER001 -ScriptBlock {Test-Path -Path $Using:p_FileName}
```

For invoke command, this lets you use local variables in the script block. This was introduced for use in workflows and can also be used in DSC script blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives to @kevmar and @mjolinor (works for PS4 at least):

```
$p_FileName = "c:\windows\system.ini"
$sb = [scriptblock]::create("Test-Path $p_FileName")
Invoke-Command -ComputerName COMPUTER001 -ScriptBlock $sb
```

$p_FileName gets resolved on the local machine so COMPUTER001 receives

```
Test-Path c:\windows\system.ini
```

Comment: Missing -Path from the command, was that a mistake ?