# PowerShell Invoke-Command on an advanced function

Tags: powershell, remoting, invoke-command

I have an advanced function `Copy-FilesHC` that is available in a module file. This function copies some files from the `Source` to the `Destination` folder and generates some output for in a log file.

The function works fine locally:

```
Copy-FilesHC -Source $Src -Destination $Des *>> $Log
```

It also works on a remote machine:

```
# For remote use we need to make it available first
Import-Module (Get-Command Copy-FilesHC).ModuleName

Invoke-Command -Credential $Cred -ComputerName $Host -ScriptBlock ${Function:Copy-FilesHC} -ArgumentList $LocalSrc, $LocalDes
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how I can have it pass the output to a log file like in the first command. When I try the following, it fails:

```
Invoke-Command -Credential $Cred -ComputerName $Host -ScriptBlock ${Function:Copy-FilesHC *>> $Log} -ArgumentList $LocalSrc, $LocalDes

Invoke-Command : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ScriptBlock'. The argument is null. Provide a vali
d value for the argument, and then try running the command again.
```

As indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448808/using-invoke-command-scriptblock-on-a-function-with-arguments) I thought the `$ sign` for the `ScriptBlock` was incorrect. But this way I don't need to put my advanced function in a ScriptBlock to copy it over as it now happens automatically while it's only available within the module. So I just need to find out how to capture the output in the log file.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution just a few minutes ago:

```
# For remote use we need to make it available first
Import-Module (Get-Command Copy-FilesHC).ModuleName

Invoke-Command -Credential $Cred -ComputerName $Host -ScriptBlock ${Function:Copy-FilesHC} -ArgumentList $LocalSrc, $LocalDes *>> $Log
```